# Convert md5 encrypted password to decrypted password wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to get real password which is converted by wordpress into md5 format.

For example,
my md5 password is - 62cc2d8b4bf2d8728120d052163a77df
Real password - demo123.

I want to get real password from md5 version.

I tried this but didn't give me what I want -http://md5encryption.com/

Comment: http://md5decryption.com/ ,, YOU ARE ENCRYPTING AN ALREADY ENCRIPTED PASSWORD, DO DECRYPT IT :)

Comment: You're not meant to decrypt, the point is to hash and then accept input and rehash it, check for a match.

Comment: Decryption not give me real password.

Comment: @Chirag1162 I checked on the website, and it returns `demo123` as the decrypted pw... check again md5decryption.com

Comment: Yes it's working in some cases but not working which contains the string like this
$P$BFdY9H9BPGKPsYsynJVDcO9XoE6ikX0

Answer (score 3):

You cannot unhash a password. That is the whole reason you hash a password in the first place.

It is possible to 'brute' force a password, or use a rainbow table to lookup the password - but that is why you (hopefully) used a salt on the password to ensure the hash is unique.